# iOS - Converting UTF8 data from backend and displaying incorrectly

Tags: ios, unicode, utf-8, character-encoding

I am writing an iOS application that receives data from the backend. I parse the NSData object (objectNotation) as below.

Everything works fine until I receive a special character in the one entity, which is:

"Test já"

When I receive this and I debug parsedObject, it shows "type" to be "Test j\U00e1"

So this is obviously some Unicode/UTF8 issue. I then proceeded to look all over stack overflow, and found various potential solutions to this and tried them all, to no avail.

```
NSString *stringTest = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:objectNotation
                                         encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];  --> does not work

NSString * test2 = [NSString
                    stringWithCString:[stringTest cStringUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]
                    encoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding]; --> does not work
```

I have tried every single encoding that Obj has to offer, and it either returns the character as \U00e1, or nil, or a bunch of garbage.

I have battled with this for hours so it is a good time to post now. I appreciate any assistance. Thank you.

Code is below:

```
NSDictionary *parsedObject = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:objectNotation options:0 error:&localError];


NSMutableArray *btms = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];



NSArray *results = [parsedObject valueForKey:@"results"];

NSLog(@"Count %d", results.count);

NSLog(@"Count %d", parsedObject.count);



[parsedObject enumerateKeysAndObjectsUsingBlock:^(id key, id value, BOOL* stop) {

    BTM *btm = [[BTM alloc] init];

    NSLog(@"%@ => %@", key, value);

    btm.number = key;

    btm.latitude = [value valueForKey:@"lat"];

    btm.longitude = [value valueForKey:@"long"];

    NSString* temp = [value valueForKey:@"type”];
```

}

Answer (score 0):

Set "application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8"  as 'Content-Type' while receiving data from the backend.

```
 [requestUrl setValue:@"application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Type"];
```

Comment: hi, thanks. I had to change my NSURLRequest to NSMutableURLRequest obviously to be able to do this. I then set the url and then call setValue as per your code. Is this correct? Unfortunately did not help.